# Using IPv6 6in4 tunnel with multiple VLANs, or LAN Interfaces?

Tags: ipv6, tunnel, pfsense

I have a pfSense router, and I've setup a Hurricane 6in4 IPv6 tunnel by following this guide:

http://thirdinternet.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Configure-6in4-Tunnel-in-pfSense.pdf

It all seems to be working well, AFAIK.

[image: ipv6 test]

This is setup with a single LAN in pfSense, and using RA to hand out IPv6 addresses (hopefully I'm using the right terminology here):

[image]

However, how do I extend this to multiple VLANs, or interfaces? Very confused here - do I simply carve up the IPv6 subnet myself, and give a small piece fo each network? Or is there a smarter way of letting pfSense/router take care of it?

Comment: Did you also get a `/48` prefix? Normally, you get the `/64` and use it as the transit to HE, and once that is working, get a `/48` from HE. Some routers can do IPv6 prefix delegation, and other require you to simply assign different `/64` networks from the `/48` prefix.